# How do I debug Chrome extension which is made of JavaScript code transformed into bunch of eval() statements?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, debugging, webpack, eval

I'm trying to build, load and debug Selenium IDE extension in Chrome. I got the source code from https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium-ide then ran `yarn build` and now I have a folder

```
<repo-root>\\packages\\side-recorder\\build
```

which contains manifest.json and all .js files listed in the manifest.json are located properly in relation to manifest.json This includes background.js file.

So it looks like build ran okay. I switch Chrome into developer mode, go to chrome://extensions and click "load unpacked", then navigate to "build" folder. The extension is added, but when I click onto its toolbar icon there's an error message in Chrome console which says it cannot connect to engine.io server. I want to find the piece of code which tries to connect there so I decide what to do next.

The problem is original code from the repo which looked like typical JavaScript code is not present in the same form in the "build" folder. Instead it's present as a bunch of `eval()` statements in background.js file.

The original code would contain something like:

```
this.attachRecorderRequestHandler = this.attachRecorderRequestHandler.bind(
  this
)
```

and I search for this code and I find this line in background.js instead... It starts like this...

```
eval("__webpack_require__.r(__webpack_exports__);
```

and it looks like all the code it just put into one line and somewhere in the middle it contains

```
this.attachRecorderRequestHandler=this.attachRecorderRequestHandler.bind(this);}
```

Even if I put a breakpoint onto `eval` and go back to

```
chrome://extensions/?id=someVeryLongLineHere
```

and reload the page then the breakpoint is not hit. Surely I cannot get anything debugged.

It looks like I'm doing something wrong because what I see doesn't match typical "hello world" debugging experience in the Chrome documentation.

How do I debug this? How do I get breakpoints working anywhere and actually debug the original code?

Comment: What happens when you take the superlong line out of the eval statement? Does that change the functionality? Then you could reformat the code so it's not just one long line (I use Notepad++ with JSTool to format JS).

Comment: @gcdev This sounds interesting but I'd rather not do it by hand. Is there any way to prevent this code transformation in the first place?

Comment: I have no idea. Not familiar with `yarn` at all. Vaguely familiar with selenium, but definitely not enough to be a helpful resource on that topic either.